# ¿Cómo obtengo un formulario al dar clic en un botón usando Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Saben si es posible que desde un botón se pueda abrir otro formulario sin que cambie de página.

Supongamos en este ejemplo:

http://note.ly/

En esa página se pueden crear un tipo de stickynotes digitales de tal manera que cuando le doy clic en el botón "mas" van apareciendo mas stickynotes.

En mi caso, tendría una plantilla como formulario  en html que sería el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <input type = "submit" value="Add more"></form> 

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "/action_page.php".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

El botón "add more" tendrá que desplegarme un nuevo formulario similar al anterior....

Honestamente no tengo la menor idea de hacerlo... Supongo que es posible hacerlo con Javascript y jugando con la etiqueta iframe...

Pienso realizar mi proyecto en JSP.

Agradecezco sus respuestas. Soy demasiado noob en crear páginas web :/

Comment: Podes usar boostrap, fijate en este link http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes Probar este fragmento de código hecho con javascript puro. Todo los nuevos formularios tienen un **ID** diferente. OJO:El css no es necesario. solo lo use para que se pueda apreciar mejor los formularios agregados. Te recomiendo que copies y pegues en un archivo HTML para que puedas apreciar mucho mejor el resultado.

```js
function clonar() {
  cantidad = 0;
  myForm = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
  cant = myForm.length;
  clonForm = myForm[0].cloneNode(true);
  clonForm.id = "form" + cant;
  document.getElementById("contenedor").appendChild(clonForm);
}
```

```css
form {
  border: 1px blue dashed;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 305px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="contenedor">
    <form action="#" id="form">
      <div>
        <label for="nomUser">Nombre de usuario:</label>
        <input type="text" id="nomUser">
      </div>
      <button>Enviar Datos</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <button onclick="clonar();">Clonar Form</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Espero que te ayude.
Saludos!

Comment: Es exactamente los que ando buscando, Muchas gracias, aunque no se donde poner el botón para el envío de datos... Osea, como hago para que me envíe los datos de mi plantilla, solo con 1 botón de "Enviar datos". ¿Bastará solo con mover el div?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes realizarlo con jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Guardas el contenido en una variable, aqui puedes realizar las modificaciones pertinentes a tu conveniencia.
  var plantilla = "<form action='/action_page.php'>" +
    "  First name:<br>" +
    "  <input type='text' name='firstname' value='Mickey'>" +
    "  <br>" +
    "  Last name:<br>" +
    "  <input type='text' name='lastname' value='Mouse'>" +
    "  <br>" +
    "<br>" +
    "  <input type='submit' value='Submit'>" +
    "</form>";
  //Obtienes el contenedor donde se va a poner el nuevo formulario
  var contenedor = $("#contenedor");
  //Obtienes el boton que acciona el agregado
  var btnAddMore = $("#btnAddMore");
  //Adjuntas un evento click al boton add More
  btnAddMore.click(function() {
    //Agregas el contenido al contenedor cuando se realice el click al boton add more
    contenedor.append(plantilla);

  });
});
```

```html
<!-- incluir jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br> Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <!-- Agregas el id btnAddMore al boton para adjuntarle un evento y agregar el contenido dinamico-->
  <input type="button" id="btnAddMore" value="Add more"></form>

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "/action_page.php".</p>
<!-- Creas un div al que se le agregan los nuevos formularios -->
<div id="contenedor"></div>
```

Ahora, no es recomendable tener muchos formularios en una misma pagina, te recomiendo utilizar ajax para enviar los datos que necesites.

Comment: Muchas gracias DanAlvarez tu respuesta sirvió a la perfeccion!